# Type extensions with a generic constraint not raising an error, nor doing what might be expected

Tags: generics, f#, generic-constraints, type-extension

Consider the following code snippet using F# 4.0, .NET 4.6:

```
type X<'T> = Y of 'T

type XS = X<string>
type XI = X<int>

type X<'T when 'T :> string> with
    static member X = 2
    static member take (s: 'T) = s

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module XS =
    let foo = 10
    let create s = XS.Y s
    let test = XI.take 2    // expected only string allowed, XI.take should not exist
```

I would expect the type extension `type X<'T when 'T :> string> with` to either be respected (in this case that would mean an error, because `string` is sealed, or restrict `'T` to be `string`), or to raise a syntax error.

What is more, I can use the following syntax as well, which would be a syntax error in a normal type definition (without `with`):

```
type X<'T> when 'T :> string with
    static member X = 2
    static member take (s: 'T) = s
```

My guess is that the constraint is simply ignored on the extension. Is that by design? Or is it supposed to work and if so, how?

I came to all this when experimenting a bit with type extensions and wondering whether I could create a specific set of methods that only apply to a specific concrete type, or a further restricted concrete type (something that can also be done by inheritance, I know).

Comment: wow! thats really strange! I am curious what the explanation will be

Comment: I suspect constraint to apply only in the initial definition ; .Net generics aren't C++ template which can be specialized ; maybe a look to what code is generated (using ILSpy for example) can give some clues

Comment: I don't think what you write in the type parameter of the type extension is taken into account . The fact that no error is shown is also an indicator that whatever you put there doesn't really matter.  
If you want to create restricted extensions write the constraint at the member definition level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the compiler should reject your code, but here are a few observations:

1. Note that the behavior is different if you use an "extrinsic" extension (e.g. by putting the definition and extension in different modules - see [Type Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions)) - there, the compiler flags the extension as an error.
2. If what you want is to have *instance* extension methods that show up only for certain concrete values of the type parameter, then you can use a C#-style extension method (this is also explained at the link above).  However, because C# doesn't support *static* extension members, there's no way to apply this trick to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it is probably a bug. I [reported it at F# Github here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1611), I wasn't aware that the type extension behaves differently in a separate module (actually, I am aware, but wasn't yesterday night ;)...)